# How to pass a String parameter from an eclipse cheet sheet to some java code and return a String value to the cheat sheet

Tags: java, serialization, eclipse-plugin, parameter-passing, command-pattern

For **tl;dr**, see the **Summary** at the bottom.
My objective is pretty much summarised in the title of the question:

*I want to pass in a string parameter from an eclipse cheat sheet, use the parameter to control the behaviour of the code, and then return a string from the code, so it can be displayed to the user in the cheat sheet.*

**Possible solution 1: using actions...**

I have a package which contains some eclipse cheat sheets. Most of the online guidance I have found talks about the use of the `<action>` element to invoke eclipse code, and together with a ICheatSheetAction, this allows the convenient `paramN = value` xml syntax.

Using actions, I have managed to get my eclipse code to receive parameters from the cheat sheet and can control the code's behaviour using the parameter(s), but the run() method of an IAction returns void, so I can't return a string. There is notifyResult(), but that only takes a boolean.

*In summary:*
**Works:**

- Calling code from cheat sheet
- Using passed parameters in the Java code

**Problem:**

- Can't return a String value to be displayed in the cheat sheet.

**Possible solution 2: using commands...**

The cheat sheet xml also allows the `<command>` element. This is slightly less convenient to use because the command needs 'serializing', but it has the advantage that the execute() method can return any java Object, including the string I want to return.

Using commands, I have also managed to invoke my eclipse code from the cheat sheet and I can return a string back to the cheat sheet and display it there, BUT I can't access the parameters I'm trying to pass into the execute() method.

*In summary:*
**Works:**

- Calling code from cheat sheet
- Returning a string to the cheat sheet

**Problem:**

- Can't access parameters passed in from the cheat sheet.

**Next Steps:**

Unless anyone can suggest a way to return a String from an Action's run() method, I don't think I can use actions to achieve what I want.

I think my best bet is using commands, and based on the first step of the cheat sheet below, it **must** *surely* be possible. The [documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/ua_cheatsheet.htm) says that I should provide a "serialized ParameterizedCommand". I think the problem is that I don't understand how a [ParameterizedCommand](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/commands/ParameterizedCommand.html#serialize()) works, and I find the documentation utterly opaque.

I could implement a command for each possible behaviour of each step of each cheat sheet, but I think that will quickly devolve into horrendous code duplication.

My cheat sheet is quite simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cheatsheet title="Example Cheat Sheet">
  <intro>
    <description>This Cheat Sheet will invoke some actions and commands.</description>
  </intro>
  <item
      title="Get a Cheat Sheet variable">
    <description>
       Pick foo or bar...
    </description>
    <command returns="selection" serialization="org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.openMessageDialog(title=Select One,buttonLabel0=foo,message=Select a button,buttonLabel1=bar)"/>
    <onCompletion><b>${selection} selected</b></onCompletion>   
  </item>
  <item
        title="Invoke an Action">
    <description>
       Click...
    </description>
    <action class="com.example.cheatsheets.CheatSheet1.CheatSheet1ActionHandler" pluginId="SimpleSerializedCommand" param1="${selection}"/>
  </item>
  <item title="Invoke a Command">
    <description>Click...</description>  
    <command returns="result2" serialization="com.example.cheatsheets.CheatSheet1.SimpleSerializedCommand.command1(firstParameter=${selection})" />
    <onCompletion><b>${result2}</b></onCompletion>
  </item>
</cheatsheet>
```

I am attempting to access parameters by using code examples I found online.
My handler looks like this:

```
public class CheatSheet1CommandHandler extends org.eclipse.core.commands.AbstractHandler {

    @Override
    public Object execute( ExecutionEvent event ) throws ExecutionException {
        String action = event.getParameter("firstParameter");
        if (action == null)
            return "I got NULL!";
        else if (action.equals( "foo" ))
            return "Hooray!";
        else
            return "Boo!";
    }   
}
```

`action` is always null.

I've set up my command within my plugin as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.cheatsheets.cheatSheetContent">
      <category
            id="SimpleSerializedCommand.CSCategory1"
            name="CSCategory1">
      </category>
      <cheatsheet
            category="SimpleSerializedCommand.CSCategory1"
            composite="false"
            contentFile="CheatSheet1Content.xml"
            id="SimpleSerializedCommand.cheatsheet1"
            name="CheatSheet1">
      </cheatsheet>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
      <category
            id="SimpleSerializedCommand.CommandCategory1"
            name="CommandCategory1">
      </category>
      <command
            categoryId="SimpleSerializedCommand.CommandCategory1"
            defaultHandler="com.example.cheatsheets.CheatSheet1.SimpleSerializedCommand.command1"
            id="com.example.cheatsheets.CheatSheet1.SimpleSerializedCommand.command1"
            name="command1">
         <commandParameter
               id="SimpleSerializedCommand.firstParameter"
               name="firstParameter"
               optional="false"
               typeId="java.lang.String">
         </commandParameter>
      </command>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
      <handler
            class="com.example.cheatsheets.CheatSheet1.CheatSheet1CommandHandler"
            commandId="com.example.cheatsheets.CheatSheet1.SimpleSerializedCommand.command1">
      </handler>
   </extension>

</plugin>
```

I suspect some more code or set-up is required - perhaps something to do with `ParameterizedCommand`s, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21122233/how-to-pass-object-parameters-in-command), but I have no idea where such code should be added.

**tl;dr Summary:**

How can I:

1. Return a String from an action to a cheat sheet, or
2. Adjust my code/plugin setup so I can access parameters passed into my command's handler

All help/pointers/constructive comments appreciated.

Comment: Your commandParameter id is `SimpleSerializedCommand.firstParameter` but you are using `firstParameter` everywhere else. Change the ids to match.

Comment: @greg-449: embarrassingly enough, it really was that simple. Would you like to post it as an answer that I can accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `commandParameter` id is `SimpleSerializedCommand.firstParameter` but you are using `firstParameter` everywhere else. Change the ids to match everywhere.

Note that the `name` attribute is supposed to be a 'human readable' name that the UI uses if it needs to display information about this.

Comment: so if my parameterID was `com.example.long.some.lengthy.fully.qualified.parameter.parameterName`, then I just have to refer to it as such in the code? I can work with that, but it's not brilliantly readable.

Comment: Yes you do. But most Eclipse code just uses a short id for command parameters since they are specific to a single command.

Comment: I'll admit I'm never quite sure how much to qualify my IDs as I'm not sure what 'domain/namespace etc.' they're in, and what they might clash with. For example, I didn't want to give my cheat sheet category the same name as my command category in case they clashed. The rest of the code I'm working with seems to include a fully qualified package name in every id. For example, what if another command had a parameter called `firstParameter`?